# What type of graph shows the relationship of time it takes to travel a certain distance?

Tags: graphing-functions

For experiment dealing with an electromagnetic train, we measured time it takes for different configurations to travel a set distance.  This data now needs to be plot on a graph.  What type of graph should be used?

Comment: Unless there is some simple relationship between the configurations, I second Stella's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a bar chart any time that you have a categorical independent variable and a numerical dependent variable, which appears to be the case here.